# Send Facebook message from application

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, send

How can I send a message to the currently logged in user from inside a Flex application contained in a Facebook iFrame and using the official AS3 Library for Facebook please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) is the easiest way to work with facebook.

http://code.google.com/p/fbas/

It's far from a complete implementation, but Graph is so simple it shouldn't take long to implement any features you need.

NOTE: When I've used it I ported the javascript portion of the example code on the project's main page to AS3 & `ExternalInterface`. It reduced external dependencies to zero (with the exception of swfobject)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Would it be possible to provide a very simple example of sending a facebook message to someone? The Flex part is clear, the Graph API part isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow you to send messages . Either way , you can post to the user's friends feed on behalf of the user , with a custom message and the the notification for the post in feed will be displayed.

Post your request to http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed

Requires the publish_stream permission.

You can refer this link http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/facebook-album.html

Comment: Is it possible to send a message as a notification automatically from a facebook application ? I have been searching a way to do just that : I didn't find ...I mean if they are providing a platform for third-party applications then notifications should be a "must-be" stuff ...